# CMake: default flags depending on build type

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake

I'm using CMake 2.8.12.2 in a project and I noticed that depending on the build type, it adds some flags to the compiler. In the case of the ***Release*** build type, it adds `-O3` and `-NDEBUG`.

The thing is that since this project is going to be used in different platforms where I don't know which CMake version they're using (above 2.8 of course) and I'd like to know if there are some default flags for each build type, or if this feature depends on the version of CMake.

I know I could add my flags to the variables `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_*`, but I want to keep the compilation "clean" by adding the flags only once and not overriding what is already done.

Answer (score 0):

This will add "-Wall" to the release flags

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -Wall")
```

Comment: Yes I know. I was asking more about the default flags cmake adds to the compilation depending on the build type.

Comment: Find out what the default is, and overwrite it yourself and make sure you never have duplicates. If you want more control, you can use the string() function provided by cmake, but I promise you it will look very messy and you won't have any help because nobody does it that way.

Answer (score 0):

`-O3` and `-NDEBUG` have been used by CMake for quite some time; so much that you shouldn't worry about them as in practice they have been independent of the CMake version.